# A question on vector subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be the vector space of all functions $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{R}$, is the set of functions which are continuous a subspace?

I think if you add functions which are continuous, the resultant function should also be continuous, but I'm not sure about it

Comment: Yes, that's true,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, continuous functions form a subspace of all functions $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Proof:

- The sum of continuous functions is continuous.
- A continuous function multiplied with a constant is continuous.

So, continuous functions are closed under vector space operations and form a subspace.